# Nodemailer not giving error if email not sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nodemailer

I'm trying to use nodemailer to send emails. But if the "to" field has wrong email address then the email is not sent, which is right. But it does not give me an error and the function gets resolved.

Below is my code:

```
const send = nodemailer.createTransport({
 host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
 port: 1234,
 secure: false,
 type: 'login',
 auth: {
  user: USER,
  pass: PASSWORD
}
})
```

```
let message = {
 from: 'some email',
 to: 'johndoe@gmai.c',
 subject: 'subject',
 html: html
}

return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
 send.sendMail(message, (error: any, result: any) => {
  if (error){
   console.log('Error')
   reject(error)
   return
  }
  resolve(result)
})
})
```

I'm using typescript btw. Never logs the error if the email is not sent or the "to" field has the wrong email. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try doing it with `async-await` instead of `promises` and see the behavior

Comment: @MohammadBasit I have already tried with async-await, but still it does not go in error condition

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can catch the error if the email is wrong but you can firstly check if the email is a valid `string` using `regex` before sending an email. So, if you get emails like `johndoe@gmai.c`. You can prevent sending wrong emails. This will not help in detecting if the email is correct or incorrect but at least it will ensure a correct email format which will decrease the no. of unwanted emails sent.

Using vanilla `JavaScript` - but can easily be converted into `Typescript` as there is not much complexity

```
try {
  let to = "johndoe@gmai.c";
  let validEmail = validateEmail(to);
   if (validEmail) {
     let info = transporter.sendMail({
       from: 'some.email'
       to: to, 
       subject: "Hello", 
       text: "Hello world?", 
       html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", 
     });
     console.log("Message sent: ", info.messageId);
   } else {
    throw "Email Not Valid";
   }
  } catch (e) {
   console.log("Error Occurred: ", e);
  }

 //A function to check if email is valid using regex

 function validateEmail(email) {
  const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9] 
    {1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
 }
```